# How do you quantify your objective-c code quality?

Tags: objective-c, code-metrics, static-code-analysis

I am currently using OCLint, which can be integrated with XCode, but the format of the result has some problems. When the # of warning exceeds 200, it cannot be properly displayed.

**What I want is more sophisticated code metrics, e.g. Cyclomatic complexity, afferent coupling, efferent coupling, NPath complexity and etc.**

Comment: isn't everyone are using `Clang Static Analyzer`?

Comment: @Bryan OCLint does more and optionally includes the clang static analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

I think most people use the Clang Static Analyzer, which is quite good and already integrated into Xcode.

Comment: what I want is more code metrics, e.g. cyclomatic complexity, afferent coupling, efferent coupling and etc. :)